# Issues with Modified by and Created By Fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We are seeing strange issues in our SharePoint Lists Created by and Modified by fields .It shows as special characters as shown below .I had already checked the User Information list and verified that everything is working fine .This issue is happening on SharePoint 2016 and its patched to the latest version .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power shell command below to show it as display name:

Get-SPUser –Web http:// | Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD

If the problem persists, you can try to create a new user profile service application, then start profile synchronization, then select start full, after that, check the effect.

Comment: Thank you though that didn't work what helped is that we had to run a script to Fix the list Schema .May be when we created the list from template its was effected